# How to call extension object inside companion from another class using kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I want to make playvideo using Exoplayer, but I have a little bit problem with how to access my extension function.

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView

class playerViewadapter {
    companion object{
      fun PlayerView.loadView(){
      }
   }
}
```

but  `loadView` extension from my `AppCompatActivity` not show

```
class Test:AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)
        playerViewadapter.loadView()
    }
}
```

How to call `loadView` from my AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 2):

You have to be in context of the object in order to invoke something of it.

`with(playerViewadapter) {  }` or `playerViewadapter.apply {  }` should do it:

Example:

```kotlin
with(playerViewadapter) {
    playerView.loadView()
}
```

[Try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/JIo-teDFj)

Comment: @AkbarGrunge what do you mean?

Comment: PlayerView is from **import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView**

Comment: @AkbarGrunge I know it is declared there, I posted a minimal example to show it. What is the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: Actually i want to make like this [https://github.com/MostafaAnter/VideoPlayerInsideRecyclerView]. But this application base on Databinding. I want to convert this without using Databinding. You can see on file **PlayerViewBindingAdapter.kt**

Comment: @AkbarGrunge if you are not using data-binding then you have to get the PlayerView object using `findViewById`: `findViewById<PlayerView>(R.id.yourPlayerViewId)` then call `loadView()` on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221627/discussion-between-animesh-sahu-and-akbar-grunge).

Comment: the problem i cannot manage my syntax SimpleExoplayer to be dynamic on Recycleview. Your solution i have try it. The result is after recycleview scrolling, another Playerview cannot stop.

Answer (score 0):

Why You define extension function in a companion object of another class? Isn't it better to define it in the file Where You have `PlayerView` or if it is not Your class, create a new file for utils functions?

```
class PlayerView
{
}

fun PlayerView.loadView()
{
}
```

And then You can call this function:

```
val playerView = PlayerView()
playerView.loadView()
```

Comment: Actually i want to make like this [github.com/MostafaAnter/VideoPlayerInsideRecyclerView]. But this application base on Databinding. I want to convert this without using Databinding. You can see on file PlayerViewBindingAdapter.kt.